# Count number of substrings which contains particular strings

Tags: python, string

I need to count the number of substrings of `s` which contains both the strings `a` and `b`.

This is what I did till now:

```
a = input().rstrip()
b = input().rstrip()
s = input().rstrip()
min_length = max(len(a), len(b))
n = len(s)
count = 0
for i in range(min_length, n+1):
    for j in range(n+1-i):
        temp = s[j:j+i]
        if (a in temp) and (b in temp):
            count += 1
print(count)
```

The above code works fine, but is slow. How can I optimise it?

**For example:**

**Input:**

```
ab
c
cabc
```

**Output**

```
3
```

Substrings of `s`, which contains both `a` and `b` as substring are `cab` , `abc` and `cabc`.

Comment: Can you give some example inputs and outputs?

Comment: Maybe start by finding all places where `a` appears in `s` and, separately, where `b` appears and `s`, and work from that?

Comment: @AChampion I have added an example in the ques, btw, my code works fine (as far as I know), so you can try it with other inputs. Just that it is quite slow

Comment: As your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it, you might find better luck at [codereview.se]. Remember to read [their requirements](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: @AChampion Thanks for the link, I have posted it there:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/202525/count-number-of-substrings-which-contains-particular-strings